# Did the four Vedas originate from Shiv Sutras?

Tags: scripture, vedas

I am curious to know and understand if the four Vedas did originate from Shiv Sutras?

Please do cite references from authentic sources, if any.

Comment: Vedas come from the rishis. Shiva sutras came after the Vedas.

Comment: @Ikshvaku vedas are divine revelations

Comment: There are two Shiva Sutras. Which one you're talking about?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto the one from which Sanskrit emerged.

Comment: @DarkKnight which are still from the rishis...

Comment: Where can I buy hard copy of this book? Any idea? @Just_Do_It

Comment: Sorry buddy no idea @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: The Śivasūtras of Pāṇini are clearly a later work. Saṁskṛta didn't emerge from these sūtras. Saṁskṛta already existed before Pāṇini.